# Number of points in the diagonal of an $X \times Y$ square lattice box.

Tags: geometry, integer-lattices

So assuming we have a $X \times Y$ lattice,
Say for example a $3 \times 5$ like so

```
* * *
* * *
* * *
* * *
* * *
```

I need to find the number of points that each diagonal passes through. In this example, each diagonal passes through 3 points. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't it just be $\min(X,Y)$?

Comment: Take a 4*3 one, it doesn't work in that case.

Comment: What is a diagonal in this case then? I assumed you meant a straight line from the corner that's not horizontal or vertical?

Comment: I am talking about the top-left/bottom-right and top-right/bottom-left diagonals. Sorry for the ambiguous wording.

Comment: Oh, now I understand your question. I misread.

Comment: Hmm...maybe it's:
$$
1 + \gcd(X - 1, Y - 1)
$$

Comment: I recall looking for something similar in the past. I think this is it. Do you want to make an answer for future readers?